# Confused by all the different ways to start & configure a flask app

Tags: python, flask

I've followed different tutorials to learn flask, and lately I've been trying do build something more substantial.  I run my flask app with `flask run`.  I have a `app.py` but no `__init__.py`.  FLASK_APP is *not* set.  I understand that because there's no FLASK_APP, flask looks for `app.py` by default.  Here's the entirety of `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from extensions import db, mail
from projects import por
from requests import requests

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

def create_app():
    print ('IN CREATE APP')

#SQL Alchemy
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI', None)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = getenv('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS', False)

# WT-Forms
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Temporary secret key'
app.config['WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT'] = None

#######

db.init_app(app)
mail.init_app(app)

app.register_blueprint(por)
app.register_blueprint(requests)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('por.por_no_sm'))

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     create_app().run()
```

I have 3 specific questions:

1. If I try to start the app with `python app.py`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`.  But Flask is installed, and I'm running that in my virtual environment from the same directory as `app.py`.  Why won't it run when I try it that way?  Is there any advantage to using `flask run` rather than `python app.py` or vice versa?
2. One of the things I want to do is put the config & setup code inside an app factory.  However, when I run with `flask run`, `create_app` doesn't run.  What's going on there?  I can *make* it run by uncommenting out the last 2 lines & looking for `app` instead of `__main__`, but shouldn't it run automatically?
3. Is there any advantage to adding a root-level `__init__.py` file?  I tried briefly, but then none of the imports at the top of `app.py` worked.  I kept getting a bunch of "No module named extensions", etc. errors.  I can fix those by prefacing the names with dots, (e.g., `from .extensions import db, mail`), but what do I gain by doing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a virtual env and you are getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`, then you have to activate the virtual environment before you can run `python app.py`
2. If you're going to use `create_app()`, then the rest of your code should go under it i.e. `app = Flask(__name__)` and all of the app variable initializations and your route should go under it. As the name 'create app' says, you are creating the app

Comment: 1.  The venv is enabled.  Still, I get the "No module named 'flask'" error.
2.  Yes, the code that actually creates the app needs to go inside the create_app function.  But, as laid out above, I should at least see the server print out "IN CREATE APP", but I don't.  Create_app() is not being called.

Comment: It won't print out "IN CREATE APP" because you have commented out the code that calls its parent function. With respect to your problem, please show us your directory structure

Comment: Hmm.  Like I said in the OP, I thought create_app got called automatically.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: From Flask documentation -  ....the command looks for an application instance named ```app or application```, then any application instance. If NO instance is found, the command looks for a factory function named create_app or make_app that returns an instance. Per the documentation, it only looks for ```create_app``` if it can't find the app instance and you already have it - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/